# How do check Identical array between two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays as below:

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3)
```

I need to check that  they are same array. I did something like:

```
$result = !empty(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
print $result;
```

Result : is `true`

But it is wrong for my requirements.

Say for example if I update the arrays:

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3, 7);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3)
```

Result : is still `true` . I need the result `false`

Question: How do I get the result that above arrays are not same after updating the array `$arr1` in PHP?

Comment: Even in the first example both arrays are not same. You want all the elements should be present right? In addition, the logic for implementation of `empty` is not right here.

Comment: Use `array_diff` for that `$resut = empty(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));`

Comment: @Neodan : would please let me know why I need `empty` before `array_diff` ?

Comment: @SelimReza if you take a look into documentation http://php.net/array_diff you will see, that `array_diff` returns an array of items. `empty` converts the result into `bool` (`true`/`false` aka `0`/`1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, your `$arr1` needs only the elements that are in `$arr2`. When `$arr1` has any new element, you claim that it is not identical.

From this understanding, you need to use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff):

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7);
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3);

if (count(array_diff($arr1, $arr2))) {
    echo 'Not Identical';
} else {
    echo 'Identical';
}
```

---

You can use `empty` instead of `count`. In that case, just switch the conditions.

---

**Explanation :**

`array_diff` gives you the difference of elements that are not present in any of the arrays. So in this case it holds:

```
Array
(
    [9] => 7
)
```

`array_intersect` gives you the intersection of elements that are present in both arrays. So in that case it holds:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 3
)
```

So, this is the reason why your `empty` function returns `true` when you use `array_intersect`.

Comment: we could use `$arr1_unique = array_unique($arr1);` in case of more duplicate ..

Comment: `array_unique` gives unique element in the same array, can't compare with 2nd array